# Python replace string matching regex format

Tags: python, regex, string, formatting

In python, i'd like to perform a fancy find and replace operation. I'm not very familiar with regex but I think this is possible using `re.sub` and perhaps some fancy grouping. I suspect this is a one liner but I've not managed to figure it out.

I have a string of the format `"SomeText 123.456.Thing SomeMoreText"` where:

- `"SomeText"` & `"SomeMoreText"` may or may not be present.
- `123` is an integer of length between 1 and 4 (0 to 0000).
- `456` is an integer of length between 1 and 3 (0 to 000) and the length of `Thing` is at least one character.
- Or perhaps more simply, it follows a regex format of `*[0-9]{1,4}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.*`
- The string may contain more than one instance where a part follows this format, I'd like to find and replace each instance following this format and leave the rest of the text as found.

And i'd like to convert it to a string of the format `"SomeText A123B456.Thing SomeMoreText"` where:

- `A` (a constant) has been inserted before 123
- `B` (a constant) has been inserted before 456
- All points `.` have been removed
- `Thing` is whatever was after the `.456` but before `SomeMoreText`
- The rest of the text (including spaces) has been preserved.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: so...what have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your latest code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use capturing groups to get `SomeText`, `123`, `456`, `Thing`, and `SomeMoreText`

```
re.sub(r'(.*) (\d{1,4})\.(\d{1,3})\.(.+) (.*)', r'\1 A\2B\3.\4 \5', "SomeText 123.456.Thing SomeMoreText")
```

Output:

```
'SomeText A123B456.Thing SomeMoreText'
```

Edit:  The above makes some assumptions about spaces.  You might also try

```
re.sub(r'(.*?)(\d+).(\d+).(.*)', r'\1A\2B\3.\4', "SomeText 123.456.Thing SomeMoreText")
```

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks. I can see where I was going wrong with the grouping too.

Answer (score 0):

So basically remove the first dot?

```
import re

str = "SomeText A123.B456.Thing SomeMoreText"

print(re.sub("\.", "", str, 1))
```

Outputs `SomeText A123B456.Thing SomeMoreText`